# Dill loads can't find custom module during profiling

Tags: ipython, spyder, profiler

I have an application designed for use in ipython, that stores objects using dill. I'm trying to use the Profiler built into Spyder, however the script I'm trying to profile fails with ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pdc' (pdc is the name of my core module). This does not happen if I run the script in the console.

The library is stored in a folder that is referenced by a .pth file (as described here) in the site-packages folder, and not managed by conda, I don't know if this is part of the problem.

This is the script I'm running the profiler on:

```
from <application_library> import pdc

hel = pdc.load_noninteractive(path='<path_to_stored object>')

<do stuff with the loaded object>
```

This is the key part of the output (with paths redacted):

```
File "~\pdc.py", line 42, in load_noninteractive
    return Project.load(path=path)
  File "~\pdc.py", line 413, in load
    from_zip = fio.extract_from_zip(path)
  File "~\file_io.py", line 166, in extract_from_zip
    objects.append (dill.loads(zf.read(info.filename)))
  File "~Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dill\_dill.py", line 316, in loads
    return load(file, ignore)
  File "~\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dill\_dill.py", line 304, in load
    obj = pik.load()
  File "~\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dill\_dill.py", line 465, in find_class
    return StockUnpickler.find_class(self, module, name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pdc'
```

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) I think you need to install your module instead of referencing it in a .pth file for things to work in our Profiler.

Comment: I've tried that as well, same problem